# decompile java class in jar file in maven repository

Tags: decompiler, jad

Using m2eclpse, class file inside jar file can be listed. However, both Jad or JD-eclipse won't work.

If I use "open with", it show the error as the following

> org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: The Class File Viewer cannot
>   handle the given input ('org.eclipse.ui.part.FileEditorInput').   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.ClassFileEditor.doSetInput(ClassFileEditor.java:652)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$19.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:3200)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow$1.run(ApplicationWindow.java:759)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow.run(ApplicationWindow.java:756)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2642)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3218)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3245)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createSite(EditorManager.java:828)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:647)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(EditorReference.java:289)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2945)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2850)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2842)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2793)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)

Any idea on how to decompile java class file from maven repository? Thanks.